# How to delete the duplicate data in arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashset

```
public class TestArticles {

public static void handlewords() throws IOException {

    String path = "C:\\Features.txt";
    String path1 = "C:\\train.txt";
    String path2 = "C:\\test.txt";

    File file = new File(path2);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);


    Features ft = new Features();
    String content = ft.readFile(path);
    String [] words = content.split(" ");

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path1);  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {       
    String [] word = line.split(" ");

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(words.length);
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(word.length);

   for(String s: words){
       list1.add(s);
       HashSet set = new HashSet(list1);
       list1.clear();
       list1.addAll(set);
    }

     for(String x: word){
        list2.add(x);
        HashSet set = new HashSet(list2);
            list2.clear();
            list2.addAll(set);
    }

   boolean first = true;
   pw.append("{");
    for(String x: list1){
        for(String y: list2){
            if(x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
                if(first){
                   first = false; 
                } else {
                    pw.append(",");
                }
              pw.append(list1.indexOf(x) + 39 +" "+ "1");
            }
        }       
    }
       pw.append("}");
       pw.append("\r\n");
       pw.flush();   
    }
     br.close();
     pw.close();

}
```

My output file something like:

1. {23 1,35 1,56 1,56 1,...}
2. {2 1,4 1,7 1,...}

The first line some data duplicated, the second line all the data in order without duplicated data. How can I delete those duplicated data? I already used hashset, however it did not work.

Comment: Your `HashSet` probably worked just fine, you just didn't override `.equals()` and `.hashcode()`.

Comment: How can I override it?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in your `list1` and `list2` are correctly unique, but in a case sensitive way. So you might have items in it like `man` and `Man`. But then in your last loop you use `x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)`, and since `"man".equalsIgnoreCase("man")` and `"man".equalsIgnoreCase("MAn")` are both true, that's how duplicates appear.

There are several ways to fix that:

- When you build `list1` and `list2`, lowercase the items
- Or, use a `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`, with a comparator that ignores case
- Change `x.equalsIgnoreCase(y)` to `x.equals(y)`

Comment: Janos, it still has the duplicated data.

Comment: Janos,I tried to use the TreeSet, it also has duplicated deta.

Comment: The input has a large data set, the first input is wordlist like: 1 word hello... and displayed line by line. And another input has couple articles, like "I am a man........" "I am a woman......"

Comment: You can see my code, I first put data in list, then put the list into hashset, at last clear the arraylist and put the set into arraylist again.

Comment: Janos, you are awesome. It works, I used the Treeset instead of hashset, and equals instead of equasIgnoreCase. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try override equals on your Hashsets, like this:

```
HashSet set = new HashSet(list1){
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.toString().equals(o.toString());
    };
};
```

Comment: Dan, I want to find a way to duplicate the data automatically instead of looking up to that string. Do you have any idea?

Comment: didn't understand your comment.. you want to take off duplicated data, right? What didn't work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the duplicated data.